# TypeError: User_info() got unexpected keyword arguments: 'is_staff'

Tags: django, django-models

I defined a table named User_info which inherited AbstractBaseUser and PermissionsMixin,when i tried to create superuser in terminal,it ocurred error...Here are my relative codes:
I have scrutinized settings.py to insure the database and AUTH_USER_MODEL is correct

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

# Create your models here.
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, account, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not account:
            raise ValueError('用户账户必须被设置')
        user = self.model(account=account, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, account, password=None, **extra_fields):
        # 创建staff用户的逻辑
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields['is_superuser'] = False  # 确保staff用户不是超级用户

        return self.create_user(account, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, account, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('超级用户必须拥有is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('超级用户必须拥有is_superuser=True.')

        return self.create_user(account, password, **extra_fields)


class User_info(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    usr_id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    account = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('M', '男'), ('F', '女')], default='M')
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    #is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'account'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name', 'usr_id', 'number', 'gender']  # 除了密码和用户名之外的必填字段

    def __str__(self):
        return self.account
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use,

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, account, password,**extra_fields):
        if not account:
            raise ValueError('用户账户必须被设置')
        user = self.model(account=account, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user
    def create_superuser(self, account, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        return self.create_user(account, password, **extra_fields)
```

您无法访问 setdefault 项目